# Jquery - How to use Hide() with a Checkbox to enable Animation(transition)?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

**Question:** How do I use JQuery Hide() with animations for Sections of a Webpage? At the moment am using *CSS:* Display none.

**Code**

*CSS*

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

*HTML*

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-event-Sports" >
<section class="hide" id="section-sports">...</section>
```

*Javascript:*

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#toggle-event-Sports').change(function() {    
            $("#section-sports").toggleClass('hide');
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: what animation do you need?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is a simple working solution of what you need:

**1. Slide up/Down animation:**

```js
$('#toggle-event-Sports').change(function() { 
    if($('#toggle-event-Sports').is(":checked"))   
        $("#section-sports").slideDown();
    else
        $("#section-sports").slideUp();
});
```

```css
#section-sports{ width:100px; height:100px; background:red; display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-event-Sports" >
<section  id="section-sports">...</section>
```

**2. Fade in/out transition:**

```js
$('#toggle-event-Sports').change(function() { 
    if($('#toggle-event-Sports').is(":checked"))   
        $("#section-sports").fadeIn();
    else
        $("#section-sports").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#section-sports{ width:100px; height:100px; background:red; display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-event-Sports" >
<section  id="section-sports">...</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sahil :)

Answer (score 1):

try this below function for hide and show section

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-event-Sports" value="1" onchange="valueChanged()">
        <section class="hide" id="section-sports">...</section>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function valueChanged()
        {
             if($('#toggle-event-Sports').is(":checked"))   
                //$("#section-sports").show();
                $('#section-sports').fadeIn('slow');
            else
                //$("#section-sports").hide();
                $('#section-sports').fadeOut('slow');

        }
       </script>
```